# How to change Text in TextCompositionEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox, textinput

C# WPF - I have a custom editable datagrid that uses my own custom columns that inherit from DataGridTextColumn. In my column class I override GenerateEditingElement so that I can automatically set things like MaxLength, CharacterCasing, etc.

The problem is that when the user highlights a cell, then types their first character, the datagrid auto enters editmode.  So my GenerateEditingElement fires and I'm able to setup the textbox.  Unfortuntately this is too late for charactercasing and the TextCompositionEventArgs already has a lower case char in it. Subsequent types characters are the correct case.

The column class PrepareCellForEdit is what fires next and this has the TextCompositionEventArgs. However, I can't seem to change the text.  I get compile errors that the setter is NOT available. (even though the intellisense help for the property does say get and set).

Is there anyway I can programmatically get my charactercasing into the textbox?
OR
How can I change that text in the TextCompositionEventArgs?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is subscribe to TextChanged event of TextBox.
But trick is that you could not update Text propery directly on this event handler.
You must use some small delay to do this.
Here is example which works OK:

```
    public struct MyData
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<MyData> oc = new ObservableCollection<MyData> { new MyData(), new MyData() };
        grid.ItemsSource = oc;
    }

    private void Grid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Style myStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
        // subsribe to TextChanged event
        myStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(TextBoxBase.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(OnTextChanged)));
        col.EditingElementStyle = myStyle;
        var binding = new Binding("Name") {Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay};
        col.Binding = binding;
        e.Column = col;
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(textBox);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;          
    }

    static void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = e.Result as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text.ToUpper();
            textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
        }
    }

    static void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);// This is the trick :)
        e.Result = e.Argument;
    }
```